# Efficent way to let objects appear/disappear

Tags: keyframes

I have some objects which I want to disappear, if they are out of view. I used the technic to keyframe viewport and render visabibilty. The main issue I have with this technic, if I want to scale my keyframes or move the keyframes it works until they disable the visability. So in Frames in which the object's visability is disabled, the keyframes are also disabled.

My workaround for now is to apply this step in the very last step. I also tried only to change visability of render, but this makes it difficult to analyse the Animation in viewport. I think this is kind of unneccessary and I hope a better solutions exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this button to view the keys from objects currently hidden:

[image]

Also, consider looking at object culling if you are using cycles, that hides objects that's out of view or far away, automatically in render. Object culling should be enabled both in render and object settings for each object that's going to be culled.

Comment: @Crantisz Important would also be to disable _Show Only Selected_ left to where your arrow is pointing at - because as soon as the object is invisible in the viewport, it is no longer selected. You have it disabled, but it should be mentioned since it's not the default.

Comment: @MartyFouts The OP is talking about seeing keyframes. It is literally stated in the question that the problem is, keyframes will be invisible as soon as the object is invisible in the viewport, but leaving them visible in the viewport makes it more difficult to analyze the animation in there since the objects don't disappear then.

Comment: @MartyFouts Quote: "So in Frames in which the object's visability is disabled, the keyframes are also disabled." Actually it is not literally said that the keyframes are invisible, but that's what they are when they are "disabled" because the object's visibility is disabled.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You're reading implications into the OP's statement by your own admission "it's not literally said".  Ask them what they really mean.

Comment: @MartyFouts You know very well that people not always find the right words. You can disable keyframes i.e. make them not contribute to the animation result, but this is not what happens when the object is invisible in viewport. They are invisible but still contribute to the animation.

Comment: So to short the discussion a bit since @Crantisz Solution was in the right direction. I actually was using the visability mostly for culling (I didn't realized this feature yet), but also for making an Object disappear after I hided it with one-directional mirrors. So his/her solution was not perfect since the Show Only Selected must be disabled to show my disabled in viewport Objects. This makes it a bit tidious, since I have to manage all keypoints at all but much more reliable than my workaround.

Comment: @MaKaNu I agree it's tedious, I don't understand why it operates like this. Disabled curves (by unchecking them in the Graph Editor) are still visible (only greyed out) but have no effect. On the other hand, if an object is invisible the keyframes are too, but still their settings affect the animation - at least while visible. That's confusing. But despite that you can select invisible objects in the outliner and properties like materials etc. are still shown in the Properties tab. It doesn't make much sense, if I want to exclude keyframes in Graph Editor I'd simply unselect the object.